# C# Webmethod unable to be called with JQuery AJAX

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, ajax, webmethod

I am trying to call a webmethod I created. The problem I'm having is that the ajax call never calls my webmethod; this is strange to me because I have another webmethod located in the same file with the same return type and parameters that is able to be referenced fine in the "url" definition of the ajax call.

My aspx document consists of the following:

File name **CS.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"  CodeFile="CS.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<script>
    function ShowCurrentTime() {
    if(document.getElementById("txtUserName").value == "" && document.getElementById("app_name").value == ""){
        alert("One of the fields must be filled out");
        return 0;
    }


    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "CS.aspx/getAppId",
        data: '{name: "' + $("#<%=txtUserName.ClientID%>")[0].value + '" }',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: OnSuccess,
        failure: function(response) {
            alert(response.d);
        }
    });
   }
function OnSuccess(response) {
    var y = document.getElementById("test");
    y.innerHTML = response.d;

    }
    </script>

    <body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
    <table style="background-color:#fcfcfc; width:30%;">
    <tr>
        <td><b>Application ID:</b> </td>
        <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtUserName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td><b>Application Name:</b></td>
        <td><asp:TextBox ID="app_name" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input id="btnGetTime" type="button" value="Search" 
            onclick = "ShowCurrentTime()" /></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <p id="test"></p>
    </body>
    </html>
```

My web method looks like the following with the filename CS.aspx.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page 
{
   [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
   public static string getAppId(string appName) {
       return "this is a string";
   } 
}
```

I've put a breakpoint at the return statement, just to make sure that the method is even called, while in debug mode, and have had no luck.

Comment: Instead of `failure` property in your ajax post, name it `error`. You should now at least see the error message.

Comment: Also ythe URL you post to is `CS.aspx/getappId` but the code behind you posted implies (from the `class _default` text) that is is `default.aspx` that you should be calling?

Comment: @DavidG When I changed the `failure` property to `error` and defined it the same way I defined the `failure` property, the only thing that happened was that an empty alert message popped up. I also tried to have it alert as a simple string of "hello" in the anonymous function for "error" , but still only had a blank alert pop up, even after clearing the browser cache. **also** The filename the webmethod is defined in is CS.aspx.cs, and what I understand at least, is that the "url" attribute is defined as `name_of_file/name_of_webmethod_in_file`. thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have a reference to jQuery if you want to make a jQuery ajax call.

Also, the parameters of your WebMethod need to match the parameter name you are passing in.  The parameter is appName:

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "CS.aspx/getAppId",
    data: '{appName: "' + $("#<%=txtUserName.ClientID%>")[0].value + '" }',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: OnSuccess,
    error: function (response) {
        alert(response.d);
    }
});
```

And in the WebMethod it is appName as well:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static string getAppId(string appName)
{
    return "this is a string";
}
```

In your code, there is a mismatch.

I would also make a habit of closing your div and form tags.

Comment: The problem was that the parameters of my WebMethod needed to match the parameter name I are passing in. Thank you!

Answer (score -2):

You need to place this service in a WCF or ASMX service and create a JavaScript proxy for it. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb532367(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: Consider expanding this answer by including some of the information in the link.

Comment: link-only answers are discouraged and may get flagged and removed.