# Show sending email status in the SUBMIT BUTTON

Tags: javascript, c#, contact-form

I am having a contact us form, where I would like to show the status of sending an email in the SUBMIT BUTTON TEXT

Here is the scenario

1. When a user is submitting the button ( Assume that the validation is all true. I am using a JS for validation) , Change the text to SUBMITTING.
2. When the mail is sent, Change the text to SUBMITTED or SUCCESS
3. If there is an error, Show ERROR TRY AGAIN

In a nut shell, the text of the SUBMIT BUTTON should change to the following
SUBMIT --> SUBMITTING (if validation is true) --> SUBMITTED( if success) OR ERROR TRY AGAIN ( if error)

I am using a C# code for the same ( Here it is)

```
public partial class contact : System.Web.UI.Page
{

[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod]
public static string mailsend(string name, string email, string phone, string massg, string service)
{
    string s = "";
    try
    {
                     MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
                     msg.From = "from-some-id.com";
                     msg.To = "to-some-id.com";

                     msg.Priority = MailPriority.Normal;
                     msg.Subject = "Enquiry from Website";
                     StringBuilder sbgroup = new StringBuilder();
                     sbgroup.Append("<table width='650' border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' bgcolor='#F2F2F2'>");
                     sbgroup.Append("<tr>");
                     sbgroup.Append("<td style='padding:5px 10px;' width='32'><span class='style7'></span></td>");
                     sbgroup.Append("<td style='padding:5px 10px;' width='180'><span class='style7'></span></td>");
                     sbgroup.Append("<td style='padding:5px 10px;' width=11><span class=style7></span></td>");
                     sbgroup.Append("<td style='padding:5px 10px;' width='380'><span class='style7'></span></td>");
                     sbgroup.Append("<td style='padding:5px 10px;' width='35'><span class='style7'></span></td>");
                     sbgroup.Append("</tr>");
                     sbgroup.Append("<tr>");
                     sbgroup.Append("<td style='padding:5px 10px;'><span class='style7'></span></td>");
                     sbgroup.Append(" <td style='padding:5px 10px;'><img src='http://yoursite.com/images/logo45.png' width='180' height='100' /></td>");
                     sbgroup.Append("<td style='padding:5px 10px;'><span class='style7'></span></td>");

                     sbgroup.Append("<td style='padding:5px 10px;' class='style3'><h1 align='right' class='style4'>Enquiry</h1></td>");
                     sbgroup.Append("<td style='padding:5px 10px;'><span class='style7'></span></td>");
                     sbgroup.Append("</tr>");

                     sbgroup.Append("<tr>");
                     sbgroup.Append("<td style='padding:5px 10px;'><span class='style7'></span></td>");
                     sbgroup.Append("<td style='padding:5px 10px;' colspan='3' bgcolor='#676767'><span style='font-family: sans-serif;font-size: 16px;font-weight: bold;    color:#ffac28;'>Enquiry From  Website</span></td>");
                     sbgroup.Append("<td style='padding:5px 10px;'><span class='style7'></span></td>");
                     sbgroup.Append("</tr>");
                     sbgroup.Append("<tr>");
                     sbgroup.Append("<td style='padding:5px 10px;' height='10'></td>");
                     sbgroup.Append("<td style='padding:5px 10px;' colspan='3' height='10'></td>");
                     sbgroup.Append("<td style='padding:5px 10px;' height='10'></td>");
                     sbgroup.Append("</tr>");
                     sbgroup.Append("<tr>");
                     sbgroup.Append("<td style='padding:5px 10px;'><span class='style7'></span></td>");
                     sbgroup.Append("<td style='padding:5px 10px;' colspan='3'><span class='style6'>You have received an Enquiry from website  Below are the details of the sender</span></td>");
                     sbgroup.Append("<td style='padding:5px 10px;'><span class='style7'></span></td>");
                     sbgroup.Append("</tr>");

                     sbgroup.Append("<tr>");
                     sbgroup.Append("<td style='padding:5px 10px;' height='10'><span class='style7'></span></td>");
                     sbgroup.Append("<td style='padding:5px 10px;' height='10'><span class='style7'></span></td>");
                     sbgroup.Append("<td style='padding:5px 10px;' height='10'><span class='style7'></span></td>");
                     sbgroup.Append("<td style='padding:5px 10px;' height='10'><span class='style7'></span></td>");
                     sbgroup.Append("<td style='padding:5px 10px;' height='10'><span class='style7'></span></td>");
                     sbgroup.Append("</tr>");
                     sbgroup.Append("<tr>");
                     sbgroup.Append("<td style='padding:5px 10px;'><span class='style7'></span></td>");
                     sbgroup.Append("<td style='padding:5px 10px;' style='border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;'><span class='style6'>Name</span></td>");
                     sbgroup.Append("<td style='padding:5px 10px;' style='border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;'><span class='style7'>:</span></td>");
                     sbgroup.Append("<td style='padding:5px 10px;' style='border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;'><span class='style7'>" + name + "</span></td>");
                     sbgroup.Append("<td style='padding:5px 10px;'><span class='style7'></span></td>");
                     sbgroup.Append("</tr>");
                     sbgroup.Append("<tr>");
                     sbgroup.Append("<td style='padding:5px 10px;'><span class='style7'></span></td>");

                     sbgroup.Append("<td style='padding:5px 10px;' style='border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;'><span class='style6'>Email ID</span></td>");
                     sbgroup.Append("<td style='padding:5px 10px;' style='border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;'><span class='style7'>:</span></td>");

                     sbgroup.Append("<td style='padding:5px 10px;' style='border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;'><span class='style7'>" + email + "</span></td>");
                     sbgroup.Append("<td style='padding:5px 10px;'><span class='style7'></span></td>");
                     sbgroup.Append("</tr>");
                     sbgroup.Append("<tr>");
                     sbgroup.Append("<td style='padding:5px 10px;'><span class='style7'></span></td>");
                     sbgroup.Append("<td style='padding:5px 10px;' style='border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;'><span class='style6'>Phone</span></td>");
                     sbgroup.Append("<td style='padding:5px 10px;' style='border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;'><span class='style7'>:</span></td>");
                     sbgroup.Append("<td style='padding:5px 10px;' style='border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;'><span class='style7'>" + phone + "</span></td>");
                     sbgroup.Append("<td style='padding:5px 10px;'><span class='style7'></span></td>");
                     sbgroup.Append("</tr>");
                     sbgroup.Append("<tr>");
                     sbgroup.Append("<td style='padding:5px 10px;'></td>");
                     sbgroup.Append("<td style='padding:5px 10px;'></td>");
                     sbgroup.Append("<td style='padding:5px 10px;'></td>");
                     sbgroup.Append("<td style='padding:5px 10px;'></td>");
                     sbgroup.Append("<td style='padding:5px 10px;'></td>");
                     sbgroup.Append("</tr>");
                     sbgroup.Append("<tr>");
                     sbgroup.Append("<td style='padding:5px 10px;'><span class='style7'></span></td>");
                     sbgroup.Append("<td style='padding:5px 10px;'><span class='style6'>Message</span></td>");
                     sbgroup.Append("<td style='padding:5px 10px;'><span class='style7'></span></td>");
                     sbgroup.Append("<td style='padding:5px 10px;'><span class='style7'></span></td>");
                     sbgroup.Append("<td><span class='style7'></span></td>");
                     sbgroup.Append("</tr>");
                     sbgroup.Append("<tr>");
                     sbgroup.Append("<td style='padding:5px 10px;'><span class='style7'></span></td>");
                     sbgroup.Append("<td style='padding:5px 10px;' colspan='3' bgcolor='#e0e0e6' style='padding:20px 10px;'><span class='style7'>" + massg + "</span></td>");
                     sbgroup.Append("<td style='padding:5px 10px;'><span class='style7'></span></td>");
                     sbgroup.Append("</tr>");
                     sbgroup.Append("<tr>");
                     sbgroup.Append("<td style='padding:5px 10px;'></td>");
                     sbgroup.Append("<td style='padding:5px 10px;'></td>");

                     sbgroup.Append("<td style='padding:5px 10px;'></td>");
                     sbgroup.Append("<td style='padding:5px 10px;'></td>");
                     sbgroup.Append("<td style='padding:5px 10px;'></td>");
                     sbgroup.Append("</tr>");
                     sbgroup.Append("<tr>");
                     sbgroup.Append("<td style='padding:5px 10px;'></td>");
                     sbgroup.Append("<td style='padding:5px 10px;' colspan='3'><span class='style9'>Note : We have detected that this enquiry has been send from IP address :</span></td>");
                     sbgroup.Append("<td style='padding:5px 10px;'></td>");
                     sbgroup.Append("</tr>");
                     sbgroup.Append("<tr>");
                     sbgroup.Append("<td style='padding:5px 10px;'></td>");
                     sbgroup.Append("<td style='padding:5px 10px;'></td>");
                     sbgroup.Append("<td style='padding:5px 10px;'></td>");
                     sbgroup.Append("<td style='padding:5px 10px;'></td>");
                     sbgroup.Append("<td style='padding:5px 10px;'></td>");
                     sbgroup.Append("</tr>");
                     sbgroup.Append("<tr>");
                     sbgroup.Append("<td style='padding:5px 10px;'></td>");
                     sbgroup.Append("<td style='padding:5px 10px;'></td>");
                     sbgroup.Append("<td style='padding:5px 10px;'></td>");
                     sbgroup.Append("<td style='padding:5px 10px;'></td>");
                     sbgroup.Append("<td style='padding:5px 10px;'></td>");
                     sbgroup.Append("</tr>");
                     sbgroup.Append("<tr>");
                     sbgroup.Append("<td style='padding:5px 10px;'><span class='style7'></span></td>");
                     sbgroup.Append("<td style='padding:5px 10px;'><span class='style7'></span></td>");
                     sbgroup.Append("<td style='padding:5px 10px;'><span class='style7'></span></td>");
                     sbgroup.Append("<td style='padding:5px 10px;'><span class='style7'></span></td>");
                     sbgroup.Append("<td style='padding:5px 10px;'><span class='style7'></span></td>");
                     sbgroup.Append("</tr></table>");
                     msg.BodyFormat = MailFormat.Html;

                     msg.Body = sbgroup.ToString();
                    // SmtpMail.SmtpServer = "relay-hosting.secureserver.net";
                     SmtpMail.SmtpServer = "dedrelay.secureserver.net";
                     SmtpMail.Send(msg);

                     return "Success";


    }
    catch (Exception er)
    {
        return  "fail";
    }

}
```

}

Thank you

Comment: can you show the ajax call you are making in your javascript? You have the return text in the json response message: https://www.developer.com/net/asp/article.php/3820451/Using-ASPNET-ScriptServices-with-Popular-JavaScript-Frameworks.htm

Comment: Its just a personal preference but your code could be a bit cleaner/efficient if you get rid of the unnecesary StringBuilder.Append calls. You can declare a multiline string `string emailContent = @"first line [line break] second line";` The relevant part is the `@` at the string declaration.

Comment: @G43beli actually there is no ajax call is made. I was just wondering whether my request is possible or not and if possible your guidance on how to achieve that.

Comment: @bradbury9 , am just a web designer turning to javascript and basic c# codes. My apologies for the crude coding. I wish to give someone a better experience when submitting a form

Comment: It is possible. Via javascript you can do set the button text, do an ajax call to the webmethod and when the ajax call is returned change the text again to whatever you want based on the ajax result. I would also disable the button to avoid multiple sendings 'cause of impatient users or double clicking. Do some research and work on the javascript code.

Comment: @bradbury9 Thank you for the confirmation. Shall look into the options available on net. Any link or supportive documents would be really helpful

Comment: There are many similar questions on stackoverflow, look for ajax call webmethod. This question has a sable answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24914679/c-sharp-webmethod-unable-to-be-called-with-jquery-ajax.

Comment: @bradbury9 ... Thank you very much. Really appreciate your help :)

Comment: the link I provided in comment one, also shows how to call the webmethod and receive the data back from it. See for example under "Using the jQuery Framework"